# How do I display the columnnames of an sql table with C#

Tags: c#, sql, fusioncharts

I am using Fusionchart to display my data. So I've created a stringbuilder, which inserts the data. I use a stackedcolumn, which is a multi-series chart.
This is how I set the value which is written inside an SQL Table.

```
            while (rst.Read())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= seriesQuantity; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    // Category-stringbuilder
                    stringbuilders[i].AppendFormat("<category label='{0}'/>", rst[0].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    stringbuilders[i].AppendFormat("<set value='{0}'/>", rst[i].ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

But then there are the seriesname, which I need to set. I do it with this code. Now the seriesnames are displayed as 1-4, but I need them to have the value of of the colunname. **How can I only display the names of the colums?**

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= seriesQuantity; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                xmlStr.Append("<categories>" + stringbuilders[i].ToString() + "</categories>");
            }
            else
            {
                xmlStr.Append("<dataset seriesName='" + i + "'>" + stringbuilders[i].ToString() + "</dataset>");
            }
        }
        xmlStr.Append("</chart>");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [GetName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getname(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

> Gets the name of the specified column.

`string colName = rst.GetName(i);`

Answer (score 1):

Why to force doors wide open? ;)

You can use `XDocument`, `XElement` class to create XML document with names of datatable columns.

Have a look here:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("ID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("sID", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("FirstName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);
dc = new DataColumn("LastName", Type.GetType("System.String"));
dt.Columns.Add(dc);

XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
XElement xRoot = new XElement("Categories");
foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
{
    xRoot.Add(new XElement("Category", new XAttribute("label", c.ColumnName)));
}

xDoc.Add(xRoot);
```

Result:

```
<Categories>
  <Category label="ID" />
  <Category label="sID" />
  <Category label="FirstName" />
  <Category label="LastName" />
</Categories>
```